# How can i use a function in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have designed a function in mysql to calculate distance between two coordinates.

function is like this:-

```
getDistance(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)

   {

       //calculate distance

         return distance;

}
```

now in my php file, i have these four argument to pass in  this function.

but i dont know how can i call this function. please tell me how can call this function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this `select getDistance(1,2,3,4)`

Answer (score 4):

While I find this structure quite strange, and feel curious about why someone would implement such things in MySQL, the way it should work is with

```
mysql_query(sprintf("select getDistance(%d,%d,%d,%d)", $a, $b, $c, $d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use string concatenation:

```
<?php
mysql_query('SELECT getDistance('.$a.', '.$b.', '.$b.', '.$b.')');
?>
```

Comment: and you have a perfect SQL injection, depending where your data comes from. Either use `int()`, `sprintf()` with `%d` or `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: I suppose I did assume that he would have that set up. All though, when It comes to mysql in PHP, PDO is the safest way.